# Multi Posts request in three files Wordfpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I need to make manageable some text in my full custom HTML/CSS theme. So I created a custom post to do it with ACF custom Field. Everything work fine !

Here the code :

```php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'infos',
));

foreach ($posts as $post) :
  $contact = get_field('contact');

   <a href="tel:<?=$contact['tel']?>"><?=$contact['tel']?></a>

endforeach
```

It's a light version to explain and it works. But...

I use this code in header.php and footer.php.

If I use it in header and footer the custom field of the Posts doesn't work in single.php
If I use it in header or footer it's work in single.php

I think in the number of request to posts (3, header, footer, single)

How can I make a single request for two files (header and footer) ?
Can I make the request before ?
I open to any idea

Answer (score 0):

We need to use [global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in this case

This code to header

```
  <?php
    global $contacts_data;
    $contacts_data = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'infos',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'no_found_rows' => true,
    ));
    
    foreach ($contacts_data as $contact_id) :
    $contact = get_field('contact', $contact_id);
    
    ?>
    <a href="tel:<?=$contact['tel']?>"><?=$contact['tel']?></a>
    <?php endforeach;  ?>
```

And this code to single.php and footer.php

```
<?php
global $contacts_data;
foreach ($contacts_data as $contact_id) :
$contact = get_field('contact', $contact_id);
?>
<a href="tel:<?=$contact['tel']?>">11111<?=$contact['tel']?></a>
<?php
endforeach;                                
?>
```

Important detail, we use in the query

```
'fields' => 'ids',
'no_found_rows' => true,
```

because we need only IDS, its significantly reduces the load on the database and speeds up the query